# Syncfusion WPF DataGrid Filter Positioning

Tags: c#, wpf, filter, datagrid, syncfusion

I would like to know if there is a way of moving the filter popup from a datagrid.
By clicking on the filter icon, i want the filter to be poped below the filter icon.
I am using syncfusion datagrid
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

@Yoan De Chaton

Syncfusion DataGrid open the advanced filter UI below filter icon by default. If the screen edge hides the popup, then the control re-positions the position of popup to view fully.

[DataGrid UI Filter Help](https://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/sfdatagrid/filtering#ui-filtering)

[Explains about popup boundary detection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750577(v=vs.85).aspx)

[image: DataGrid Filtering]

Thanks,
Sivakumar
Note: I work for Syncfusion.